# Single word for "in a holy way"

Tags: single-word-requests

I was writing a satirical story, and wanted a single word to express the concept of "in a holy way" or "in a holy manner". For example, were it actually a word, a good example would be "holy-ly". For a specific instance in which it might be used:

> So, the priest walked into a bar with a rabbi and a monk?
>
> Yes, but he did it oh-so-[in a holy way], so everyone was overawed.

A compound word or phrase would be acceptable. However, I'm not a huge fans of neologisms, so nothing constructed please. I would strongly prefer an adverbial form, but would accept it if no such suitable word exists.

Comment: It would help to have a better example. You might speak in a holy way, perform a ritual in a holy way, dispense charity in a holy way, or even generally act in a holy way, but how do you walk into a bar in a holy way? (With dignity and stateliness? With humility or love for all? While chanting something or waving an incense-burner? Surrounded by a halo of light? While shouting "Get out and go to church, you sinners"?)

Answer (score 1):

As OP has presumably noticed, most words with the sense sought here only really exist as *adjectives* that don't naturally have associated *adverbial* forms *(**holy, hallowed, blest, venerated, sanctified, consecrated,...**)*.

It doesn't *necessarily* connote theism / religion, but noting usages like *His reverence the Reverend Green* in [Cluedo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluedo#Characters), the best I can come up with is...

> **reverently**
> [*showing great respect and admiration*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reverent) <sub>(Cambridge Dictionary)</sub>

...where I think it's fair to say "reverently" and "in a holy way" are near-synonymous in OP's specific context.

Comment: I think I prefer "piously" from the comments, but this is also a strong choice, so I'm upvoting this answer. Hope it's not an insult that I'm not accepting it.

Comment: No problem. Personally, I'd normally expect ***pious / piously*** to be *facetious, disparaging* words in any conversational context ***I*** might be involved in (which at least for me doesn't apply with ***reverent/ly***). But you're the author, so you should use whatever works for you.

Comment: I mean, what I'm writing is satirical and does disparage to a degree the religiosity of the person about whose religiosity I'm commenting. So the potential facetiousness of "piously" actually seems like a boon for me, rather than a potential flaw, and so you're entirely right!

Answer (score 1):

***holily*** is a word.  An adverb.

In a holy manner; with sanctity or devoutness. [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/87721?redirectedFrom=holily#eid)

> 1754   J. Edwards Careful Enq. Freedom of Will iv. vii. 236   To act
> holily and wisely in the highest possible Degree.

It's in the Bible, too, actually.  King James Version:

> 1 Thessalonians 2:10 Ye are witnesses, and God also, how ***holily***
> and justly and unblameably we behaved ourselves among you that
> believe: